# Processing Two Complex Inputs (removing lists of duplicate symbols in a list)

Tags: scheme, racket

This question is from Exercise 17.6.5 of [htdp](http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-22.html#node_sec_17.3). I need some guidance on how to determine if a pair of symbols is unique in a list of lists.

Here's what I've got thus far:

```
;; pair : symbol, list of symbols -> list of list of symbols

;; an auxiliary function that returns a list of possibly non-unique 
;; lists of pairings from a name (symbol) and a list of names (list of symbols).

;; output from (pair 'Alice '(Bob Charlie))
;; (list 
;; (list 'Alice 'Bob) (list 'Bob 'Alice) (list 'Alice 'Charlie)
;; (list 'Charlie 'Alice) (list 'Bob 'Charlie) (list 'Charlie 'Bob))

(define (pair name alist)
  (cond
  [(empty? alist) empty]

  [(cons? alist) (append (pair name (first alist))
                         (pair name (rest alist))
                         (pair (first alist) (rest alist)))]

  [else (list (append (list name)(list alist))
              (append (list alist)(list name)))]))
```

If this function is applied to the question (5 names), it yields 30 lists of pairs of symbols, of which 10 are duplicates. What is an appropriate way to remove them? In other languages one way to solve this problem is to introduce a side-effect by creating a data structure and to insert each item into the structure, but only if it is not already in it.

I've considered sorting but realized that I'm unable to sort symbols since I can only test for equality, so I'm pretty much stuck here and would appreciate any insight.

Edit:
I've added my function definition of "non-same" which consumes a name (symbol) and produces lists of pairs.

```
(define (non-same name alist)
  (cond
    [(empty? alist) empty]
       [(equal? name (first (first alist))) (cons (first alist) (non-same name (rest     alist)))]
       [else (non-same name (rest alist))]))
```

The following test passes:

```
(non-same 'Mary (pair 'Mary '(Jane Laura Dana Louise)))
;; outputs (list (list 'Mary 'Jane) (list 'Mary 'Laura) (list 'Mary 'Dana) (list 'Mary 'Louise))
```

So it seems I'm on the right track. Unfortunately it seems I've arrived at the solution through serendipity and now must wrap my brain around how it works LOL.

Thanks for all who read this question and especially to Chris for his helpful comments.

Comment: No, there are still problems here.  Chris is absolutely right when he tells you to use "arrangements", defined earlier. It produces all possible arrangements of a list of names, and is not the same as your 'pair' function. Among other things, it accepts a different number of arguments.  If you were in my class, I would be pedantic and insist that you follow the design recipe; you're missing a whole bunch of steps.

Comment: John, thanks for the input. Yes, my "pair" function was the result of not understanding what was required and in fact complicated it. Part of the reason was that I failed to understand that the output from "arrangements" was supposed to represent a circularly linked list, so there is no need for a "pair" function to represent a giver-recipient pair.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the question, I have a feeling that you're barking up the wrong tree.

You only need three functions: `random-pick`, `non-same`, and `arrangements`. The last one is already defined in exercise 12.4.2.

I presume from your question that you want to implement `non-same`. You will want to implement a function that you pass into `filter` (or whatever the HtDP equivalent is). Then, it's as simple as:

```
(define (non-same names arrangements)
  (define (usable? arrangement)
    ...)
  (filter usable? arrangements))
```

(Fill in the `...` yourself, of course. That function needs only return a boolean value, and you should not have to touch `append` at all (as you did in your question).)

I hope that's enough of a hint. If you need another hint, just ask. :-)

Comment: Chris, you're right, I need to implement non-same. The "pair" function is similar to "arrangements"; it takes a name and produces combinations from it. I'll update my post to reflect what I mean since comments have a character-count limit.